# Grep with datetime and id in log file

Tags: linux, grep

I am trying to use grep command to extract the line containing the date and id both, but facing some difficulty.
When I am using the command

```
grep "$(date+"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")" catalina_pi.log
```

this is giving me every line with date but when I am doing piping with the 'id' like

```
grep "$(date+"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")" catalina_pi.log | grep "518643640"
```

this is giving the line containing the 'id' but the datetime is not there and also an error which says

```
date+"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S: command not found
```

But in the first command this is not giving me that error.
So I need some help in getting the line which contain both 'datetime' and 'id'.
This is the data in my log file:

```
[2018-01-31 18:34:44.044] [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-9] DEBUG c.v.w.handlers.SocketMessageHandler -
                Message received : {"Id":"518643640","userId":"3142"}  
[2018-01-31 18:34:44.044] [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-9] DEBUG c.v.w.handlers.SocketMessageHandler -
                Message received : {"Id":"518643640","userId":"3142"}  
[2018-01-31 18:34:44.044] [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-9] DEBUG c.v.w.handlers.SocketMessageHandler -
                Sending message : {"id":301,"errorCode":403,"description":null}
```

My expected output is

> [2018-01-31 18:34:44.044] [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-9] DEBUG c.v.w.handlers.SocketMessageHandler -
>                       Message received : {"Id":"518643640","userId":"3142"}
>       [2018-01-31 18:34:44.044] [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-9] DEBUG c.v.w.handlers.SocketMessageHandler -
>                       Message received : {"Id":"518643640","userId":"3142"}

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Line with the date and id only not the ones which do not contain the id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the line containing the `ID` and the line preceding it containing the `DATE`, use the below command.

```
grep <id> -B1
```

`-B1` option will print one line before the line containing the search string.

Example:

```
grep "518643640" -B1
```

Will give you the below output:

```
[2018-01-31 18:34:44.044] [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-9] DEBUG c.v.w.handlers.SocketMessageHandler -
            Message received : {"Id":"518643640","userId":"3142"}  
[2018-01-31 18:34:44.044] [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-9] DEBUG c.v.w.handlers.SocketMessageHandler -
            Message received : {"Id":"518643640","userId":"3142"}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it Worked.

Answer (score 0):

To get the entire line,

```
$ n="2018-01-31 18:34:44.044"
$ grep "$n" file | grep "518643640" file
```

For current date,

```
$ n=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

To get only the Id `<digit>` provided the `date` string exists in the line,

```
$ grep "$n" file | grep -o -P '(?<=Id":")[0-9].*(?=",)' file
```

Another one liner using `awk`:

```
$ awk -v var1="$n" -v var2="518643640" '($0 ~ var1 && $0 ~ var2) {print}' file
```

Comment: your first command $ n="2018-01-31 18:34:44.044"
$ grep "$n" file | grep "518643640" file does not giving the datetime.

Comment: First line is to show you an example and according to the input in your question... use the second one where current date is assigned to n.